# How to maintain whitespace in javascript generated from typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, whitespace

I want the javascript code generated from typescript to have the same white spacing. Long story short, we're migrating from js to ts and maintaining whitespace would allow us to compare generated code against the unmigrated version of the code.

My input ts looks like:

```
id = this.getOrCreate(
    entity.uuid,
    dao.wrap(utils.trimProxyPrefix(entity.name)),
    dao.wrap(entity.type),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetName),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetType),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetIp),
    dao.wrap(host),
    dao.wrap(version),
    dao.wrap(status)
);
```

The output looks this ugly super long line:

```
id = this.getOrCreate(entity.uuid, dao.wrap(utils.trimProxyPrefix(entity.name)), dao.wrap(entity.type), dao.wrap(entity.targetName), dao.wrap(entity.targetType), dao.wrap(entity.targetIp), dao.wrap(host), dao.wrap(version), dao.wrap(status));
```

My expected output would be:

```
id = this.getOrCreate(
    entity.uuid,
    dao.wrap(utils.trimProxyPrefix(entity.name)),
    dao.wrap(entity.type),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetName),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetType),
    dao.wrap(entity.targetIp),
    dao.wrap(host),
    dao.wrap(version),
    dao.wrap(status)
);
```

My tsconfig looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "./src/real/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Just minify and stop caring ;)

Comment: Though there is a configuration option about comments (`--removeComments`, defaulting to false), I'm not aware of any that would preserve whitespace, especially because the output may vary significantly depending on the target compatibility level required. Is the explicit goal to preserve your _existing_ whitespace, or would it be equivalent to [use auto-formatting tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) to format the before-and-after code into similar style conventions for review?

Comment: It's more convenient to compare against the unmodified existing. I have to jump through a few more hoops if I have to apply a formatter to the existing code because the review goes through a rbcommons. If it's not possible to maintain white space, I might have to jump through those hoops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transpiled TypeScript code could be significantly different depending on the `tsconfig.json` configuration, so preserving whitespace isn't really an option in the compiler.

One thing you could do is to first run your source through a formatter like [Prettier](https://prettier.io/), and also run it again post-compile (`prettier --write **/*.ts` should do the trick). That should minimize the diffs you see between the source and target code.

Comment: I ended up going with prettier over js-beautify because prettier consistently wrapped arguments to a function by always inserting a newline. js-beautify produced different results for the js and js from ts code. However, I had to remove all empty newlines because prettier did consistently handle that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using prettier and also removed empty lines on both the before migrating to ts and js code generated from ts then posted a review to rbcommons that compared the 'cleaned' code.

For information about prettier, see Oleg's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57470670/1810962

To remove the empty lines i used a bit of bash:

```sh
for i in `ls`; do  sed -i .bak  '/^[[:space:]]*$/d'  $i ; done
```